# How to get the value assigned to a variable inside a variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, types

A1, A2,...  are assigned to t. And A1, A2, A3,.... are further have values as assigned in below for loop.
Now when I am printing print(t(1,:)), I want the answer 2, but I am getting A1. This is just a dummy code of my actual problem, the A1, A2 actually having 500 x 1 values.

```
t=['A1';'A2';'A3';'A4';'A5'];
for j=1:length(t)
    eval([t(j,:), '= 2*j'])
end
```

Can anyone help out how to deal with this problem in eval.

Comment: There’s a difference between the variable `A1` and the string `'A1'`. I think think that instead of creating so many variables with numbers attached, you should create an array of arrays: `A{1} = […]`, `A{2} = […]`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do not create variables with dynamic names like this. It will cause you to write slow obfuscated code. It is better to use arrays, cell arrays, or struct variables. Read ["TUTORIAL: Why Variables Should Not Be Named Dynamically (eval)"](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval) on MATLAB Answers for a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 1):

```
eval(['t(',num2str(j),',:)= 2*',num2str(j)])
```